# How can I strip unneeded drivers from Ubuntu kernel build?

Tags: drivers, kernel

Referencing:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Supposedly, one ought to be able to remove unnecessary drivers from the kernel build script via:

```
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

Yet - every time I do this to disable building drivers that seem a no-brainer (e.g. disabling wireless drivers for a bare-bones VM guest kernel), there's a bunch of opaque check for dependencies that fail.

Is there a way to do this safely, without having to read every line of every script?

Answer (score 0):

Use menuconfig to browse and search for kernel options. Install ncurses-dev first to use the menu in the terminal.
Download the source from kernel.org, untar it, and type

```
make menuconfig
```

in the source directory. 
I found this guide particularly helpful for customizing the kernel:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-building-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel/